# Can an OCSP response in DER format be converted to PEM (and back to DER)?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ocsp

I'm working on adding OCSP stapling to my server application. It was decided that the application itself won't query the OCSP responder, but rather another process that will periodically fetch an updated response and write it into a local database. However, the database has issues storing the certificate in DER format.

My question is if much like with X509 certificates, is DER to PEM a valid conversion (and then back to DER in order to staple it), or do we need to find some alternative way to store the response in the database (e.g. base64)?

Edit: Expanding the question based on Crypt32's input: can I perform this conversion using OpenSSL's C API? As far as I can tell there's support for that only with `X509` objects, but I can't convert an OCSP response DER to `X509` in order to do this conversion.

Comment: As far as I know there is no PEM defined for OCSP. But you can use any encoding of binary data you want to store it in a database, i.e. base64, uuencode, hex, ... . Just decode it again when retrieving the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can manually convert binary DER to Base64-encoded string to store in database. It is up to you how you will store the data as long as you can get a binary copy of stored data when pure binary data is required (i.e. in OCSP stapling). That is, when receive binary data, convert it to Base64 string and save in database as text. When you need to read this data, read Bas64 string from database and convert back to byte array and pass this array to target application.

Comment: By saying that, do you mean that converting the staple to PEM is not supported? And base64 is the way to go?

Comment: PEM is same base64 string with some header and footer. For storage purpose you can use custom PEM header/footer just to identify the content type.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Please have a look at my edit in the original question. I'm try to figure out if OpenSSL's API offers a way to make this conversion, or if I need to go for a non-OpenSSL solution - any idea?

Comment: You even don't have to use any specific tools. Most programming languages provide sort-of easy way to convert byte array to base64 string and vice versa. And `DER to X509` is a bit meaningless. DER is the encoding of the data, while `X.509` is a structure of the data.